# construct an FA (theory of automata)

Tags: theory, finite-automata, automata

You are required to construct a finite automaton for the language of all those strings whose length is **odd**, but contain an even number of b’s defined over the alphabet {a,b}.

I have done this

```
((a+b)(a+b))*bb+bb*((a+b)(a+b))
```

but I know this is wrong, so what is the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You say you are looking for an automaton, but your (wrong) answer is a regular expression. I will provide an automaton. It uses two counters mod 2; one for the length, one for the number of b. So the states are:

```
q[0,0], q[0,1], q[1,0], q[1,1]
```

where e.g. q[0,1] means that the total length is even (first zero) while the number of b is odd (the one). So the final state is q[1,0] while q[0,0] is initial.

The transitions are rather obvious, doing the necessary changes for the counters:

```
q[0,0] reads a  ->  q[1,0] 
q[0,0] reads b  ->  q[1,1]
q[0,1] reads a  ->  q[1,1]  
q[0,1] reads b  ->  q[1,0]
q[1,0] reads a  ->  q[0,0] 
q[1,0] reads b  ->  q[0,1]
q[1,1] reads a  ->  q[0,1]  
q[1,1] reads b  ->  q[0,0]
```

Comment: I think you mean "It uses **two** counters..."

Comment: Correct. Edited. Thanks @FilipAllberg